# Past Simple: before or earlier

Tags: tense

Can I use "before" with past simple? Or "earlier" is better?

- Wear this shirt. This one is better.
- I told you it is okay. I wore it before/earlier. (meaning a moment ago)

Answer (score 2):

"Before" tends to mean at some point in the past, whereas "earlier" tends to refer to some point earlier **that day**. Either is grammatically correct, but they have different meanings in my experience.

I'm not sure how much of a rule this is, but I would say "I've worn it before", but "I wore it earlier". This is also what I have heard other people say.

Answer (score 0):

In conversation many native speakers would use present perfect and many would use simple past in that scenario:

> I don't recognize that shirt you're wearing.
>   --Really? **I've worn** it many times before.
>
> Is that a new shirt?
>   --No, **I wore** it before.

Some would even say

> **I've wore** it before.

which is considered substandard; the standard past participle of **wear** is **worn**.

I suspect the use of the simple past there, with **before**, would correlate  with a lower than average "grade reading level" or with a person who had grown up in a milieu where the grade reading level was lower than average.

But **before** in this context does not mean "a moment ago", contrary to what you say in your question. It means "prior to now".

> I've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: What about "earlier"?

Comment: **earlier** goes better with the simple past than with the present perfect, when it means "just a while ago".  "Have you seen Bob? -- Yes. He **was** here earlier."  **earlier** confines the action to the past.  **before** refers to the past event in relation to the speaker's "origo" in the present.

Comment: You're welcome. Just to be clear, these  temporal nuances are processed by native speakers automatically, so to speak, without any deliberate cogitation.

Comment: ***I've worn it before.*** with an n.

Comment: @Lambie: Did you even read the answer before shooting off your comment?

Comment: I believe you said it was substandard but you never posted what is, in fact, standard. So I did. It's logical to **post both** or just the standard but not the substandard alone. Wouldn't you agree??

Comment: @Lambie: "...which is considered substandard; the standard past participle of wear is worn."   It's right there, dude.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, it isn't, You only **wrote out** the substandard which can be confusing to a person who asks the question as they have to mentally do it and might not.

Comment: @Lambie: I have no idea what you're talking about. The answer clearly states "the standard past participle of **wear** is **worn**."  What do you mean by "wrote out"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo To write out an answer in full. To write out: make a full sentence as in: No, I've worn it before.

Comment: @Lambie: Do you mean like this:  *Really? **I've worn** it many times before.*